# EF6 Code First Relação entre entidades

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net, entity-framework

Estou a tentar criar um modelo de dados de Condomínio em ASP.NET com SQL Server. Esbarrei na criação da relação do `proprietario(1)` com a `fracao(many)`.

O erro devolvido é:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Fracao_dbo.Proprietario_ProprietarioID". The conflict occurred in database "WebCond", table "dbo.Proprietario", column 'ProprietarioID'.

As minhas classes:

```
[Table("Fracao")]
public class Fracao
{


    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int FracaoID { get; set; }

    public int? ProprietarioID { get; set; }
    public virtual Proprietario Proprietario { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int CondominioID { get; set; }
    public virtual Condominio Condominio { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int ZonaID { get; set; }
    public virtual Zona Zona { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(4), Display(Name = "Letra")]
    public string Letra { get; set; }

    [Required, Display(Name = "Área")]
    public decimal Area { get; set; }

    [Required, Display(Name = "Permilagem")]
    public decimal Permilagem { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(4), Display(Name = "Piso")]
    public string Piso { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(10), Display(Name = "Porta")]
    public string Porta { get; set; }

}

[Table("Proprietario")]
public class Proprietario
{

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int ProprietarioID { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(255), Display(Name = "Nome")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(500), Display(Name = "Morada"), DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Morada { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(30), Display(Name = "CPostal")]
    public string CPostal { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(100), Display(Name = "Localidade")]
    public string Localidade { get; set; }

    [StringLength(10), Display(Name = "Telefone")]
    public string Telefone { get; set; }

    [StringLength(10), Display(Name = "Telemovel")]
    public string Telemovel { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress), Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [StringLength(10), Display(Name = "Contribuinte")]
    public string Contribuinte { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Fracao> Fracoes { get; set; }
}
```

Procurei criar as entidades da forma que criei outras e que estão bem, mas estas não.

Parece-me que o problema está relacionado com o *cascade delete*, e que tenho de criar as devidas exceções, mas não sei quais.

Comment: Você não tem nenhuma classe de mapeamento, todo o mapeamento está feito nessas duas classes ?

Comment: Não tenho classe de mapeamento. Será essa a solução?

Comment: O proprietário que você está tentando inserir na tabela Fração, existe na tabela Proprietário?

Comment: @BetaSystems-RodrigoDuarte No `Code First` é utilizado um esquema chamado `convention over configuration` então não precisa outra classe para mapeamento.

Comment: @Jhonatas Kleinkauff Na classe de inicialização da BD tenho os dados que julgo necessários. Ex: new Fracao
                {
                FracaoID = 1,
                CondominioID=1,
                ZonaID=2,
                ProprietarioID=1,
                Letra = "A",
                Piso="-4",
                Porta="GAR 19",
                Area=34.7m,
                Permilagem=4.6m, 
                }

Comment: O proprietário: ProprietarioID= 1,
Nome= "Nome do proprietatio",
Morada= "Morada do Prop ",
CPostal= "1000-285",
Localidade= "Lisboa",
Telefone= "",
Telemovel= "",
Email= "",
Contribuinte= "",
 },

Comment: @VitorCanova, não é via de regra isso, pode ser feito o mapeamento.

Comment: @ASoares, não é necessário, foi mais uma pergunta para entender como é sua estrutura. Todas as outras classes estão exatamente como essa, certo ?

Comment: @BetaSystems-RodrigoDuarte Sim, só coloquei porque achei que você estava procurando aquele arquivo de vínculo quando se usa o primeiro modelo do `Entity`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você poderia tentar com o seguinte, código:

```
[Table("Fracao")]
    public class Fracao
    {


        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int FracaoID { get; set; }

        public int? ProprietarioID { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty("ID")]
        [ForeignKey("ProprietarioID")]
        public virtual Proprietario Proprietario { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int CondominioID { get; set; }
        public virtual Condominio Condominio { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int ZonaID { get; set; }
        public virtual Zona Zona { get; set; }

        [Required, StringLength(4), Display(Name = "Letra")]
        public string Letra { get; set; }

        [Required, Display(Name = "Área")]
        public decimal Area { get; set; }

        [Required, Display(Name = "Permilagem")]
        public decimal Permilagem { get; set; }

        [Required, StringLength(4), Display(Name = "Piso")]
        public string Piso { get; set; }

        [Required, StringLength(10), Display(Name = "Porta")]
        public string Porta { get; set; }

    }
```

Porque com o `[ForeignKey("ProprietarioID")]`, você fala para a anotação que a `FK` é a definida dentro da mesma.

**ATUALIZAÇÃO**

Errata, não me atentei ao fato de que o seu identificador tem o mesmo nome que a chave estrangeira, então, por favor, retire a anotação `[InverseProperty("ID")]`.

**ATUALIZAÇÃO 2**

Com o código a seguir, que eu repliquei inteiramente na minha máquina, funcionou perfeitamente, tente fazer o mesmo, como teste, como um novo projeto:

Classe do DbContext:

```
public class TesteContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Fracao> Fracoes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Proprietario> Proprietarios { get; set; }
}
```

Classe da Fração:

```
[Table("Fracao")]
public class Fracao
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int FracaoID { get; set; }

    public int? ProprietarioID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ProprietarioID")]
    public virtual Proprietario Proprietario { get; set; }

    [StringLength(4), Display(Name = "Letra")]
    public string Letra { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Área")]
    public decimal Area { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Permilagem")]
    public decimal Permilagem { get; set; }

    [StringLength(4), Display(Name = "Piso")]
    public string Piso { get; set; }

    [StringLength(10), Display(Name = "Porta")]
    public string Porta { get; set; }

}
```

Classe do Proprietário:

```
[Table("Proprietario")]
public class Proprietario
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int ProprietarioID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255), Display(Name = "Nome")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [StringLength(500), Display(Name = "Morada"), DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Morada { get; set; }

    [StringLength(30), Display(Name = "CPostal")]
    public string CPostal { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100), Display(Name = "Localidade")]
    public string Localidade { get; set; }

    [StringLength(10), Display(Name = "Telefone")]
    public string Telefone { get; set; }

    [StringLength(10), Display(Name = "Telemovel")]
    public string Telemovel { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress), Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [StringLength(10), Display(Name = "Contribuinte")]
    public string Contribuinte { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Fracao> Fracoes { get; set; }
}
```

E os códigos de um programa de console:

```
using (var db = new TesteContext())
{
    // Create and save a new Blog 
    Console.Write("Enter a name for a new Blog: ");
    var name = Console.ReadLine();

    var proprietario = new Proprietario { Email = "oi" };
    proprietario = db.Proprietarios.Add(proprietario);
    db.SaveChanges();

    var fracao = new Fracao { Area = 1, Proprietario = proprietario };
    db.Fracoes.Add(fracao);
    db.SaveChanges();

    // Display all Blogs from the database 
    var query = from b in db.Fracoes
                orderby b.Area
                select b;

    Console.WriteLine("All blogs in the database:");
    foreach (var item in query)
    {
         Console.WriteLine(item.Area);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Com esse código, você consegue inserir uma Fração e um Proprietário, fazendo o vinculo corretamente, se você quiser fazer a atualização, você terá que fazer o seguinte:

```
var fracao = new Fracao { Area = 1, Proprietario = null, ProprietarioId = proprietario.ProprietarioId };
```

Tente novamente com esses códigos e comente se você conseguiu.

Comment: Não resultou: The InversePropertyAttribute on property 'Proprietario' on type 'WebCond.Models.Fracao' is not valid. The property 'ID' is not a valid navigation property on the related type 'WebCond.Models.Proprietario'. Ensure that the property exists and is a valid reference or collection navigation property

Comment: Desculpa, eu não me atentei ao fato que o seu ID é o mesmo nome que a FK... Retira o "InverseProperty", por favor.

Comment: @Rodrigo: Com o [ForeignKey("ProprietarioID")] e sem o [InverseProperty("ID")] não dá erro de constraint, mas não coloca dados nas tabelas

Comment: @Rodrigo: O resultado é o mesmo: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Fracao_dbo.Proprietario_ProprietarioID". The conflict occurred in database "WebCond", table "dbo.Proprietario", column 'ProprietarioID'.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Vou tentar fazer o inverso: criar as tabelas em SQL Server povoá-las com dados e depois com EF criar as entidades a partir do SQL Server. Depois digo o resultado.

Comment: @ASoares, está muito estranho isso... Faça isso e me avise, se quiser, podemos tratar direto por email (rodrigo.duarte@betasystems.com.br). Abraços

Comment: @Rodrigo: Mesmo estranho, tanto que estive a validar todos os dados (93 Fracoes e 61 Prop) e encontrei o problema numa fracao que o Prop não constava. Asneirada da grossa :|. Mas serviu para conhecer um pouco melhor o EF.

Comment: Que bom que resolveu! :)

Answer (score 2):

Na classe `Proprietario`, põe um constructor que initializa a `ICollection<Fracoes>`. Por exemplo:

```
public class Proprietario {

   public Proprietario( ) {
      Fracoes = new List<Fracao>( );
   }

   ...

   public virtual ICollection<Fracao> Fracoes { get; set; }

}
```

Assim, configura corretamente o `One-To-Many` relação entre os modelos. Há um artigo [aqui](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) em inglês que explica também.

**Atualização**

Criei meu próprio Code-first e copiei as suas classes do jeito que estão, com a minha modificação (não incluí `Zona` ou `Condominio` só). Ao final, tive uma classe assim:

*Fracao*

```
[Table( "Fracao" )]
public class Fracao
{
    [ScaffoldColumn( false )]
    public int FracaoID { get; set; }

    public int? ProprietarioID { get; set; }
    public virtual Proprietario Proprietario { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength( 4 ), Display( Name = "Letra" )]
    public string Letra { get; set; }

    [Required, Display( Name = "Área" )]
    public decimal Area { get; set; }

    [Required, Display( Name = "Permilagem" )]
    public decimal Permilagem { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength( 4 ), Display( Name = "Piso" )]
    public string Piso { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength( 10 ), Display( Name = "Porta" )]
    public string Porta { get; set; }
}
```

*Proprietario*

```
[Table( "Proprietario" )]
public class Proprietario
{
    public Proprietario( )
    {
        Fracoes = new List<Fracao>( );
    }

    [ScaffoldColumn( false )]
    public int ProprietarioID { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength( 255 ), Display( Name = "Nome" )]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength( 500 ), Display( Name = "Morada" ), DataType( DataType.MultilineText )]
    public string Morada { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength( 30 ), Display( Name = "CPostal" )]
    public string CPostal { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength( 100 ), Display( Name = "Localidade" )]
    public string Localidade { get; set; }

    [StringLength( 10 ), Display( Name = "Telefone" )]
    public string Telefone { get; set; }

    [StringLength( 10 ), Display( Name = "Telemovel" )]
    public string Telemovel { get; set; }

    [DataType( DataType.EmailAddress ), Display( Name = "Email" )]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [StringLength( 10 ), Display( Name = "Contribuinte" )]
    public string Contribuinte { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Fracao> Fracoes { get; set; }
}
```

E acabei com tabelas e colunas assim:

[image: exemplo de tabelas e colunas geradas pelo Code-First do Entity Framework 6]

Comment: Matt: fiz como estava no artigo e as tabelas são todas povoadas com dados, no entanto o SQL Server adiciona à Proprietario uma nova coluna: Fracoes_FracaoID estando sempre Null

Comment: @ASoares agora não sei exatamente o que acontence ... atualizei minha resposta com minhas experiências com suas próprias classes. Deu tudo certo.

Comment: A sua resposta também está certa. O que aconteceu foi que eu estive a rever os dados das classes (93 frações e 61 proprietários) e descobri uma fracção que tinha um ProprietarioID que não constava em nenhum dos proprietários. Foi asneira minha, mas tinha revisto os dados todos e tinha-me escapado. Obrigado!

Comment: Ótimo! É bom que conseguiu achar o "raíz" do problema, como dizem aqui :)